# Getting a Variable While App is Running in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an app running in Xcode so I am able to see all the logs. I want to get a specific variable in that app while it is running and connected to Xcode. Is there any way to do that? By putting in some kind of command to print the current value of the variable on a certain page that is currently open. I don't have any break points set as of now. I just really need to get the value of the variable for debugging purposes.

Comment: If you add a break point to where the variable sits and step through, the debug area will display the variable and it's value.

Comment: When you see the variable in the debug area you can then right click and print the variable and it's description

Answer (score 2):

You could use something such as NSLog or print to display the variable, through it would only show whats in it at that specific moment

Something along the lines of

```
NSLog("Text: \(variable)")


print(variable)
```

Comment: I want something that we don't need to change the code within the app to check. Can this happen without re running the app?

Comment: what is the difference between nslog and print?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without breakpoints. And I don't really understand how you expect it to happen.

For example, you have a page controlled by class `MyAwesomeViewController`. It has some variables defined inside function `viewDidLoad`. You can't access them at any point of time at least because they will be deallocated after you leave `viewDidLoad` and not initialized before you enter it.

I would suggest you put some breakpoints.

Comment: I want to access variable that are not deallocated yet and are in the view controller itself.